# @ModelAttribute for complex objects

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have a user entity that has many attributes (some fields not shown here):

```
@Entity
public class User {

    @OneToOne(cascade = ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private File avatar; // File is a custom class I have created

    @NotEmpty
    @NaturalId
    private String name;

    @Size(min = 6)
    private String password;

    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Role role;
}
```

In my thymeleaf template I have a form that submits **username**, **password** and **avatar** (`MultipartFile`). Now in my controller instead of these parameters...

```
@PostMapping("/register")
public String register(@RequestParam String username,
                       @RequestParam String password,
                       @RequestParam MultipartFile avatar) { ...
```

...I want to use `@ModelAttribute @Valid User user`. My problem is that:

1. password first should be encrypted then passed to the user entity,
2. bytes[] from `MultipartFile` should be extracted then stored in user entity (as a custom `File` object),
3. some other fields such as `Role` should be set manually in the service class.

How can I take advantage of `@ModelAttribute`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Instead of trying to shoehorn everything into your `User` class, write a `UserDto` or `UserForm` which you can convert from/to a `User`. The `UserForm` would be specialized for the web and converted to a `User` later on.

The conversions you are talking about should be done in your controller (as that is ideally only a conversion layer before actually talking to your business services).

```
public class UserForm {

    private MultipartFile avatar; 

    @NotEmpty
    private String username;

    @Size(min = 6)
    @NotEmpty
    private String password;

    public UserForm() {}

    public UserForm(String username) {
         this.username = username;
    }

    static UserForm of(User user) {
        return new UserForm(user.getUsername());
    }

    // getters/setters omitted for brevity
}
```

Then in your controller do what you intended to do (something like this):

```
@PostMapping("/register")
public String register(@ModelAttribute("user") UserForm userForm, BindingResult bindingResult) {
    if (!bindingResult.hasErrors()) {
      User user = new User();
      user.setName(userForm.getUsername());
      user.setPassword(encrypt(userForm.getPassword());
      user.setAvataor(createFile(userForm.getAvatar());
      userService.register(user);
      return "success";
    } else {
      return "register";
    }
}
```

This way you have a specialized object to fix your web based use cases, whilst keeping your actual `User` object clean.

Comment: This is a good answer (because it replaces a bunch of parameters with a single parameter in our handler method) but it doesn't solve all of my problem. If you compare my code with yours, you see that you have added just an intermediate object and instead of directly getting request parameters, we are getting them from a DTO! I Think This is a disadvantage of DTOs here. I wanted to avoid DTOs. I should rephrase my question to ask is it possible to **directly** bind form fields to my object attributes?

Comment: It isn't because you have to do conversion from web related classes (your `MultipartFile` to your `File`) and to do encoding on your password. So there is to be some manual juggling. Also the role shouldn't be send to the front-end because you want to set it manually. This way you also avoid a user (accidentally) updating its role!. Using an entity directly in th view might be possible with simple use cases but when things get more complex you shouldn't shoehorn those into your entities but rather solve them at the correct layer.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can just use a setter to make all these actions. When Spring is mapping data to fields, and you have setters in the entity, it will use them to pass data. You can preprocess data in this way and set final values to fields.

Comment: You mean in my `User` entity I should have something like: `public void setFile(MultipartFile file){ this.avatar = new File(file.getBytes());}` and it automatically works?
Could you please add a sample code.

Comment: You don't want to do things like that, as that ties your domain to Spring and to the web!. (`MultipartFile` is part of Spring, you want to keep Spring out of your domain/entities as much as possible). `MultipartFile` is in a web package which would mean your domain/entities would be tied to the web layer (which is also something you want to prevent!).

Comment: I'm not sure about file upload as I didn't try this but it could work, you can try this. This is probably simplest solution but not clean as M. Deinum said.

Answer (score 0):

```
 @PostMapping("/register")
public String register(@ModelAttribute User user, Model model) { // remember if You have another name for parameter and backing bean You should type this one @ModelAttribute(name="userFromTemplate") User user
    encryptPassword(user.getPassword); //remember that is sample code, You can do it however You want to 
    extractBytes(user.getAvatar); //same here
    user.setRole(manuallySetRole);
    model.addAttribute("user", user);
        return "success"; // here u can redirect to ur another html which will contain info about ur user
    } else
        return "redirect:sorry";
}
encryptPassword(String password) { ... }
same for the rest methods
```

Here i give You sample code how to use @ModelAttribute in your example. If You have questions feel free to comment.

Comment: That won't work for the `File` argument (unless you would write a converter/tap into spring binding).